# file_get_contents won't work with my Google CSE API URL

Tags: php, api, google-api, file-get-contents, google-custom-search

I want to use **file_get_contents** to get content from this Google CSE API `https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={My-KEY-HERE}&cx=015435574869060730302:bycrgaosjuu&q=intitle:funny` but it return me **failed to open stream: No error** ,I tried to change **https://** with **http://** but it return me **failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden**

How do I get Google CSE API contents With file_get_contents?

Comment: Try requesting a file from another foreign server. Some web hosts have blocked that feature so it might be not possible on your server.

Comment: I tried now from another web-host but the problem is the same

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem in file_get_contents function, you are just not authorised, double check the keys and check the google console for IP restriction on API, and check if application is ON

Comment: I just did, every thing is normal